# Accessing an object property based on an array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to access an object property based on the first value in it's array.

```
var LANGS = {
    "C#": [10, "text/x-csharp", "code"],
    "C/C++": [7, "text/x-c++src", "code"]
};
```

So I want to be able to access `"C#"` by the `10` in its array, how would I do this?.

Comment: what does that even mean "*access "C#" by the 10 in its array*"?

Comment: @Amit get the key `C#` if `10` is provided

Comment: @Tushar if you're correct, I'd say don't do that. Setup a new "dictionary" with a proper key.

Comment: What about if there are two keys with the same number? E.g. both c# and C++ have 10 as first value? Should it return only the first or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for-in` to loop through the object's property names, and then get the value of the property using the name in order to check its first element:

```
var LANGS = {
    "C#": [10, "text/x-csharp", "code"],
    "C/C++": [7, "text/x-c++src", "code"]
};
function getEl(number) {
    for(var el in LANGS) {
        if(LANGS[el][0] == number) {
            return el;
        }
    }
}
alert(getEl(10));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgp4zazq/

Comment: Why the downvote? This makes an assumption about what to do having found the property, but it does what the question asks: Shows how to find the property based on the value.

Comment: @Tushar: Huh? Why would `indexOf` apply here?

Comment: @Tushar What'd you write? `arr.indexOf([10, "??"]);`? This makes no sence. //T.J. Crowder thanks... That was my duty but... :D

Comment: Would be good practice to change  `for(var el in LANGS) {` to `for(var el in LANGS) if LANGS.hasOwnProperty(el) {` in the answer, to make sure that function only loops over defined elements.

Comment: @Tushar: The question was quite clear: *"based on the **first** value in it's array"*

Answer (score 0):

```js
var LANGS = {
    "C#": ["text/x-csharp", "code",10],
    "C/C++": [7, "text/x-c++src", "code"]
};
function getEl(number) {
    for(var el in LANGS) {
        debugger
        var array = [];
        array = LANGS[el];
        
        if(array.indexOf(number) > -1) {
            return el;
        }
    }
}
alert(getEl(10));
```